# Connect to satellite tv receiver, tv remote control iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, television

I've been googling for a while looking how I can develop a remote control for satellite TV receiver. I've heard that LG TV's have an internal server which receives requests from an app for example, the TV and the mobile device must be in the same WiFi connection. Do the satellite TV receivers have this server as well? Can anyone point me to the right direction on how to accomplish this? or give me a start point.

Any suggestions?